# Why does a trajectory take infinite time to reach a critical point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove that:

For an ODE system $x'=F(x,y),y'=G(x,y)$ where $F,G$ are smooth, any trajectory, which doesn't start at a critical point, cannot reach a critical point in finite time.

I have this counter example. Let $F=0,G=3y^2$. Consider a trajectory $(x(t),y(t))=(0,t^3)$ that starts at $t=-1$. It seems to me that at $t=0$, it will reach a critical point $(0,0)$.

1. What is wrong with my example?
2. How should I actually prove the statement required?

Thanks.

Comment: Your trajectory does not satisfy the given ODE since $y'(t)=3t^2\ne 3t^6=y^2(t)$ for most $t$.

Comment: @  Christian Blatter: Oh, silly me, mixing up y and t. Can you please help me with proving the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Assume such a trajectory exists, and consider what this would imply for uniqueness of solutions of the system $x'=-F$, $y'=-G$.